# Where to find documentation on earlier version of GDB?

Tags: documentation, gdb, gnu

Where to find documentation on earlier version of GDB?  The documentation located at http://sourceware.org/gdb/documentation/ is for current version only.

I am specifically looking for the document "Debugging with gdb" for GDB version 7.3.1.  The document currently available at http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/ is not preferable, since it is for later GDB version 7.5.50.20121217.

At my workplace, we are using GDB 7.3.1, and hence this need.

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't asking for a recommendation.  It's asking for the location of a specific version of a specific document.  Bizarre to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At my workplace, we are using GDB 7.3.1, and hence this need.

Download the 7.3.1 [tar ball](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.3.1.tar.gz), and (these may need to be adjusted, typing them from memory):

```
cd gdb-7.3.1
./configure
cd gdb/doc
make html
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying that, but it is not yet working.  After downloading 7.3.1 tar ball and extracting, I did `cd gdb/doc; make html` and got the following error message:  make: *** No rule to make target `html'.  Stop.

Comment: @user1909987 Answer updated. Generally, you should *not* expect exact step-by-step instructions here.

Comment: I tried the updated instructions, but they too don't work for me.  The `configure` step went through without any error, but the `make` step failed. Error message was "configure: error: no termcap library found".  It could be an issue with my environment that I need to dig into deeper.